# Why does the QgsVectorFileWriter have probelms creating vector files?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, spatialite, sqlite

I am using QGis 2.0.1 and have tried to create a new GIS feature file (SQLite, Spatialite, and Shapefile) of a subset of the data. I am then saving a copy of the style of this layer and applying it to the new layer. Also, I am starting with a Spatialite database.

All three have different issues:

SQLite - The data is copied, but the fields loose their edit widget type (If you go in to the properties of the layer, then the Fields menu on the left; it is the Edit widget drop down.)

Shapefile - The file has no features in the table, but everything else is fine.

Spatialite - QGis locks up.

Shapefile code:

```
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(layer_path,
                                 'CP1250',
                                 fields,
                                 QGis.WKBPoint,
                                 crs,
                                 'ESRI Shapefile')

    if writer.hasError() != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        raise IOError('Can\'t create the file: {0}\n'.format(layer_path))

    for feature in features:
        writer.addFeature(feature)

    del writer
```

SQLite code:

```
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(layer_path,
                                 'CP1250',
                                 fields,
                                 QGis.WKBPoint,
                                 crs,
                                 'SQLite')

    if writer.hasError() != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        raise IOError('Can\'t create the file: {0}\n'.format(layer_path))

    for feature in features:
        writer.addFeature(feature)

    del writer
```

Spatialite code:

```
    spatialite = ["SPATIALITE=YES"]

    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(layer_path,
                                 'CP1250',
                                 fields,
                                 QGis.WKBPoint,
                                 crs,
                                 'SQLite', spatialite)

    if writer.hasError() != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        raise IOError('Can\'t create the file: {0}\n'.format(layer_path))

    for feature in features:
        writer.addFeature(feature)

    del writer
```

I have also tried `spatialite = ["SPATIALITE=YES", ]`

I just want to know if there is anything else that I can do to get this to work the way I want.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the edit widget issue? Are you using custom settings there? How are you trying to copy those settings?

Comment: I noticed that I am getting a multipoint error on the Shapefile. I changed the `QGis.WKBPoint` to `QGis.WKBMultiPoint`. That fixed the Shapefile issue, but how do you create a Spatialite database as I like that format much better as I have had too many corrupted Shapefiles in the past.

Comment: Please edit your question and narrow it down to what you really want to know.

Comment: It might help if you can say where the "empty" spatialite came from? Are you possibly trying to use a newer file format with QGIS compiled against an older spatialite library?